# Swift collection view index out of range determining first cell

Tags: swift

I'm trying to set the first collection view cell to be different the rest of my cells. I pulling a list of posts from the firebase database and I'm trying to make the first cell a create cell with a grey background like the picture below but I'm getting an index out of range.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HomeCell

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    } else {
        cell.list = lists[indexPath.item]

        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

    }

     return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return lists.count + 1
}
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Swift uses a Zero-Index. `if indexPath.row == 1` should be `== 0`

Comment: Does `CreateCell` and `HomeCell` have different UIs?

Comment: No, how can I add both If i create a CreateCell? @PGDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you need different `UIs` for `CreateCell` and `HomeCell`, you need to create separate `UITableViewCells` for that.
2. In `tableView(_:cellForItemAt:)` `dequeue` the type of `cell` separately based on the `indexPath.row`.
3. `First row` in the `tableView` has `indexPath as 0` and `not 1`
4. Also, you need to use `self.lists[indexPath.row - 1]` instead of `self.lists[indexPath.row]` to configure `HomeCell`

Here is the compiled code of what I mean,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CreateCell", for: indexPath) as! CreateCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        //configure your cell here...
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
        let list = self.lists[indexPath.row - 1]
        //configure your cell with list
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect except it is going over the top of one of the post cells. How can I fix this?

Comment: Add the screenshot.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. It's exactly what I want it's just covering the first post cell.

Comment: I didn't understand.